# Tap Gesture to Hide Navigation Bar, Tab Bar, and Status Bar

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, show-hide

I am trying to implement a tap gesture on my web view to hide/show the navigation bar, tab bar, and status bar.  I have the hiding/showing of the navigation bar working fine and I can hide the status bar but not get it to show back up.  The tab bar items get hidden but the bar is still there.  Can anyone help with this?

```
- (void)toggleBars:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{   
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    BOOL statusBarHidden = YES;

    BOOL barsHidden = self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!barsHidden animated:YES];

    BOOL tabBarHidden = self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden;
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:!tabBarHidden];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIBarButtonItem *systemAction = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = systemAction;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleBars:)];
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    singleTap.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

EDIT:  It looks like the tab bar is hiding but my webview just isn't filling the empty space.  How can I have it fill the space when the tab bar is hidden?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your status bar never unhides because you never tell it to. As written your code merely tells the status bar to hide every time it is executed.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden] withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden animated:YES];
```

Additionally, I'm not sure about the details of why your tab bar isn't hiding properly, but I did find the following category which claims to be able to hide the tab bar with option animation.

https://github.com/idevsoftware/Cocoa-Touch-Additions/tree/master/UITabBarController_setHidden

Comment: For iOS7 make sure to add View controller-based status bar appearance = NO in your .plist file for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I got the status bar to hide/show by adding this to my toggleBars method, but I still haven't figured out why the tab bar items hide but not the tab bar itself.

```
if (([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES))
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
```

Comment: Actually, the status bar never actually hides.  It goes through the animation like it is hiding/unhiding but the navigation bar is still the only thing going away.

Comment: I prefer: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden] withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];`